# Getting [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup: in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, http

**Scenario**

The backend team of the project I'm working in has prepared an api endpoint. I'm required to make a POST call. I am using [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to make API calls from my app, the latest version of it.

**Code**

*get_app_labels.dart*

```
class GetAppLabels {
  static Future<http.Response> getAppLabels() async {
    try {
      return http.post(
        Uri.parse(
          "https://dev-dhabi.fh.ae/api/v1/config/getAppLabels",
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("api exception -> $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

*map_app_labels.dart*

```
class MapAppLabels {
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> mapAppLabels() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await GetAppLabels.getAppLabels();
      print("response -> $response");
      return [];
    } catch (e) {
      print("mapping exception -> $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem**

When I call `MapAppLabels.mapAppLabels()` in `initState()` of my `SplashScreen`, I get the following error: **[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup: 'dev-dhabi.fh.ae'**

**Sanity Checks**

I have ensured the following are in place:

*android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I am testing on a physical device, and there is proper internet connection on it.

I have checked the URL of the API thouroughly.

**Request**

I would like to know what is the cause of this error and how to solve it.

Comment: The endpoint seems to be offline. I see no response on pinging it.

Comment: I was asked to add 20.233.23.33  dev-dhabi.fh.ae to my hosts file in C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

Before adding this line the URL wouldn't open.

Comment: Update: @schmeekygeek even after adding the lines, when I `ping dev-dhabi.fh.ae` I get request timed out.

However, when I call the POST request in Postman, it gives me a valid response. Do you know why it's working in Postman?

Comment: Maybe because postman is able to resolve the dns by looking up the host file but dart doesn't, which is why it says that it failed the host lookup. Edit: Try adding the ip address directly in the Uri.parse() method. Reference link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/host.html

Comment: @schmeekygeek it was indeed an issue with the url. It was not public. On making it public all started working fine.